# Как сделать nth-child на 3 через 3?

Tags: html, css

Нужно закрасить фоном 4,5,6 - 10,11,12 - 16,17,18 - и так далее

```css
.container div:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background: #cfcfcf;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>и тд</div>
</div>
```

Также если можно пример как сделать 2 через 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nth-child указывает лишь шаг, потому надо использовать несколько объявлений.

```css
.container div:nth-child(6n+6),
.container div:nth-child(6n-1),
.container div:nth-child(6n-2) {
  background: #cfcfcf;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
  <div>21</div>
  <div>22</div>
  <div>23</div>
  <div>24</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container > div:nth-child(6n+4),
.container > div:nth-child(6n+5),
.container > div:nth-child(6n+6)

{
    background: #cfcfcf;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>и тд</div>
</div>
```

> Также если можно пример как сделать 2 через 2

[Учитесь](https://snipp.ru/html-css/nth-child).